# Extracting multiple Wikipedia pages using Pythons Wikipedia

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I am not sure how to extract multiple pages from a search result using Pythons Wikipedia plugin. Some advice would be appreciated.

My code so far:

```
import wikipedia as wiki
import pprint as pp
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
question = 'New Zealand'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
results = wiki.search(question)
print("Wikipedia search results for our question:\n")
pp.pprint(results)

page = wiki.page(results[0])
text = page.content
```

How can I get `page` to hold all the different search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the hard part, the results are already in the `results` variable.

But the results need parsing by the `wiki.page()` nethod, which only takes one argument.

The solution? Use a loop to parse all results one by one.

The easiest way will be using for loops, but the list comprehension method is the best.

Replace the last two lines with the following:

```py
text = [wiki.page(i).content for i in results]
```

You should get all the texts in the `text` variable, which is a list.